# How to check if a nodeseq is a child/leaf node in an XML?

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark, xml-parsing

I have an `XML` which I am parsing with the help of the `xPaths` and self-made parser. The `xPaths` are just for the childnode as of now but it may not always be true, so I want to make my parser smart enough to check if the xPath is for a leaf node or not. I am thinking to check if the last element of the `xPath` has further children or not, if so, I will not consider making table from this, also will delete this `xPath` to avoid further processing, but if it has no children(i.e it is leaf node) I will fill a column with its **text**.

For example :

```
xpath : /Document/DocumentData/Creation_dt
```

I am traversing till `Creation_dt` anyways, I wish to know if `Creation_dt` has further children or not, if so, delete this `Xpath`. Currently, I am moving towards each element by using `\` operator on the `parent-nodeseq`.

Is there any way I can achieve what I wish?